# how to run more then one process through terminal

Tags: command-line

I am having some trouble in starting more then one process in a single terminal window..

like as i have started wvdial by

```
sudo wvdial
```

it shows all initiating process details but wont give back

```
pankaj@N5010:~$
```

until i press ctrl+c to terminate which causes terminate wvdial..

what i want is to start both wvdial and nautilus in same terminal window.Is it possible??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append the first command with an ampersand **&** which makes the command run in the background. *man bash* says:

If a command is terminated by the control operator &, the shell executes the command in the background in a subshell. The shell does not wait for the command to finish, and the return status is 0.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can. Just append the ampersand character (&) at the end of the command. This will allow the program to run as a background job in the shell. Like this:

```
sudo wvdial &
nautilus
```

It's worth nothing that you will still see terminal output from the task while it's running in the background.