# Improving sound quality on a Lenovo Legion 5

Tags: sound, lenovo

I have a Lenovo Legion 5, which came installed with Windows. I setup a dual boot with Ubuntu 20.04. I've noticed the sound quality on Windows is pretty good, but on Ubuntu it's quiet and flat; I've had to use overamplication just to get a decent volume level sometimes. I have no idea how to diagnose this issue and fix it. I assume it has something to do with drivers, but I lack knowledge in this area and would appreciate some direction.

I did notice this answer: [Sound quality is good on Ubuntu but great on Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/597710/sound-quality-is-good-on-ubuntu-but-great-on-windows), but I'm not sure if it's still valid due to age. If so, someone let me know if I should use those results?

Comment: @guiverc TIL. I'm on 20.04 then, unless I'm looking at the wrong thing...